# Running a groovy script created in STS(Spring Tool Suite) using the command line

Tags: windows, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have used the STS(Spring Tool Suite) to create a compiled groovy script which exists as a file on windows called Test.class. I am able to right click on the file in STS and execute it which works well.

However - I want to be able to execute the script on the windows command line, so far I have tried various ways but have not been successful. I have tried the following...

> java -cp C:\Users\MyName\springsource\sts->
>   3.1.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.codehaus.grails.bundle_2.1.1\content\lib\
>   org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-1.8.8.jar Test.class

But that does not work it gives me an error --> Error: Could not find or load main class Test.class

Any Pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test is naked? (without package name?) try this.

```
java -cp C:\Users\MyName\springsource\sts-> 3.1.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.codehaus.grails.bundle_2.1.1\content\lib\ org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-1.8.8.jar;. package.Test
```

Pay attention to ;. and package name.

Comment: I tried combinations of that and could not get it to work. Should the Package.test match the file name as well?

Comment: Sorry ,should be ";." (semi-colon and dot). Class name is same as your file name if no class defined.

Run from you root dir.

Comment: See comments to my original post

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run a test case, so you really ned to be launching junit and ass this test as the test to run.

The easiest thing to do is to download a distribution of groovy, unzip, and run:

```
groovy Test.groovy
```

Comment: I was trying to execute code on the Windows command line, not in the groovy shell (in which I know it works). Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

### **Step 1**

In STS(Spring Tool Suite) ,Create a Groovy Class e.g. Customer.groovy file. Specify a Package Name e.g. com.customer. In the main method put in code to validate the code is being called e.g. println ‘test’.

### **Step 2**

Go to your command line (Windows use command prompt). Switch\cd to the ROOT directory of your project. Execute the command below.

### Step 3

execute java -cp C:\Users\Profile\springsource\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.codehaus.grails.bundle_2.1.1\content\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-1.8.8.jar;. com.customer.Customer
The code should run.

### V Important

If like me, you do not have a class and you only have a groovy script then in step#3 specify the Groovy script name without the suffix.